# Does sleep status and paralyze remove confuse?

Tags: pokemon

Let's suppose I make the opponent's pokemon confuse, then after that I use an attack that would make it sleep, or paralyze, does it removes the confuse status? And if so, does it remove poison and burn too?

Answer (score 1):

The "turn the card" special conditions are mutually exclusive (the most recent one applies), but the "place a counter" special conditions are not.

From the [rulebook](https://assets.pokemon.com//assets/cms2/pdf/trading-card-game/rulebook/swsh6_rulebook_en.pdf):

> Removing Special Conditions
>
> > When a Pokémon evolves or moves to the Bench, it recovers from all Special Conditions. The only Special Conditions that prevent Pokémon from
> > retreating are Asleep and Paralyzed. **Since Asleep, Confused, and Paralyzed all rotate the Pokémon card, whichever one happened last to the
> > Pokémon is the only one that is still in effect. Since Poisoned and Burned use markers, those don’t affect other Special Conditions.** An unfortunate
> > Pokémon could be Burned, Paralyzed, and Poisoned all at the same time!

So yes, a Pokémon that is Paralyzed currently, and then I attack it with an attack that makes it Confused, would remove Paralysis and make it Confused instead; but it would not impact Burned or Poisoned.

Comment: Does it mean that, say, a paralyzed [Spinda](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Spinda_(EX_Hidden_Legends_48)) can cure their own paralysis by attacking with The Hula-la and making themselves confused?

Comment: No, because it can't attack if it's paralyzed (and paralysis goes away after the turn anyway).  You could do the opposite though, cure confusion with sleep or paralysis.